# 'std::string' has no member named 'front'

Tags: c++, string

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    string str;
    string str1;
    int h = 0;
    cin >> str;
    if (str.length() > 10)
    {
        str1 += str.front();
        h = str.length() - 2;
        string s = to_string(h);
        str1 += s;
        str1 += str.back();
        cout << str1;
    }
    else cout << str;
    return 0;
}
```

compiles in XCode, but doesn`t on codeforces.ru/

```
 сan't compile program.cpp:
program.cpp: In function 'int main()':
program.cpp:23:21: error: 'std::string' has no member named 'front'
program.cpp:27:29: error: 'to_string' was not declared in this scope
program.cpp:32:21: error: 'std::string' has no member named 'back'
```

Comment: show us the code as well please

Comment: string::front is introduced in C++11. Are both compilers compliant with C++11?

Comment: Perhaps that website uses a non-compliant compiler.

Comment: The code you posted shouldn't compile anyway - there's no `using` declaration, yet `std::string`, `std::cin` etc. are un-qualified.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One thing is that `string::front` and `std::to_string` are introduced since C++11. You have to make sure that you are using a compiler that supports those new features.

Comment: @user2441104 You are welcome. Hope that it helps. You can find other posts in SO that deals with XCode to support C++11.

Answer (score 5):

`string::front` was introduced in c++11. On a mac make sure you are using clang, because g++ is not as updated on osx, and use the command line options `clang++ -std=c++11 your_program.cpp`. You may also need to use the option `-stdlib=libc++`

Comment: You can also install less ancient versions of gcc on the mac.

Comment: @juanchopanza But if he has the most current version of xcode installed he is guaranteed to have clang 3.1 i think

Comment: True that. But I just re-read the question and it seems everything is already OK with XCode.

Comment: @juanchopanza when you install xcode you can install command line tools and those are the compilers that get used in the rest of your computer, there is no reason to install your own c,c++ compilers on osx

Comment: Well, there is, if you want to use a specific compiler. I have had to do that in the past, to use recent versions of GCC. But OP doesn't have that problem.

Comment: I think most people believe that clang is better, clearer error  messages, gcc has better optimizations but I've heard clang will likely catch up soon, also clang supports obj c which gcc doesn't, also better c++11 support