# 'std::string' has no member named front

Tags: string, qt, function, gcc, c++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string buff, resultstr, userstr;

string convert(const string& userstr)
{
    buff = userstr.front();
    resultstr = userstr;
    resultstr.front() = '_';
    resultstr = resultstr + buff + "ay";
    return resultstr;
}
```

That's my code, I'm using QT Creator 3.1.0 with GCC 4.9.0 as a compiler, this gives me:

```
in function 'std::string convert(const string& userstr)':
'const string' has no member named 'front'
'std::string' has no member named 'front'
```

I googled around and found in an [older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16861535/stdstring-has-no-member-named-front) here that this would occur if your compiler doesn't support C++11, but GCC should have supported that since 4.8. am  I doing something wrong? I'm brand new to C++ so I wouldn't be surprised.

Note: I skipped the "main" function because it's only being used to load the QT GUI.

Comment: "GCC should have supported that" - but only if you tell it to. Did you specify `-std=c++11` in the compiler arguments?

Comment: I did not, not quite sure how to do it either.

Comment: Got it! I had to add "QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11" to my .pro (qt project) file :) Thank you!

Comment: @Cestarian add `CONFIG += c++11` line to your .pro file. It is better because it works with Visual Studio and other compilers.

Comment: @Nazar554 I think that's useful enough that you should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make `gcc` and other compilers work in C++11 mode you should add `CONFIG += c++11` to your .pro file. Then `std::string` will have a member `.front`. It is better than adding `-std=c++11` to `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS` because it will work with any compiler supported by Qt (Visual Studio, Sun Studio, etc). The downside to this that you will need a Qt 5 or higher version of`qmake`. `qmake` will then read the required flag from your compiler `mkspec` (`QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_CXX11`) and append it to `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS`.