# std::string values become corrupted in Qt 5

Tags: c++, qt, stl, stdstring

I am trying to use the [Presage](http://presage.sourceforge.net) text-prediction platform in a Qt5 project but keep getting errors due to std::strings being corrupted.

I have this class providing string contexts for the predictive system:

```
class SomeClass : public ParentClass
{
public:
    SomeClass(const std::string& _past_context) : past_context(_past_context) { }

    std::string get_past_stream() const {
      return past_context;
    }
    std::string get_future_stream() const { return empty; }

private:
    const std::string& past_context;
    const std::string empty;

};
```

This context is called inside the Presage code like this:

```
std::string ContextTracker::getToken(const int index) const
{
    std::stringstream pastStringStream(context_tracker_callback->get_past_stream());
    ...
}
```

If I send `past_context` to `std::out` inside the `get_past_stream` method, it shows the correct string. If I send the results of `get_past_stream` in the `getToken` method, I get corrupted data.

**UPDATE [2016-07-28]:**

To clarify the question and remove the duplicate tag: the issue only happens when using Qt5. Compiling with `g++` a test case consisting only of `SomeClass` and the Presage context caller works fine. It is when using the STL in Qt5 that the strings get corrupted after being used as return values.

Comment: I added some clarification about the issue. I also added a new comment to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

After narrowing the possibilities to the passing of `std::string` as return values in Qt5, I found a similar problem here: ['std::string' has no member named front [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23445132/stdstring-has-no-member-named-front)

It seems Qt5 must be explicitly configured to use C++11 STL. Thus, adding `CONFIG += c++11` solved my issue too.

Comment: It isn't very clear how this answers your question.

Comment: This answers the updated question. The issue only occurs when using Qt without the C++11 configuration option enabled; C++ without Qt works fine.