# Why presage->predict() return a empty vector only in Qt5?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, qt5

I'm trying to use the [Presage text-prediction platform](http://presage.sourceforge.net/) in a Qt5 project but keep I get an empty vector(vector of strings). The issue only happens when using Qt5.

I read a similar question but it doesn't solve my problem ([similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38622444/stdstring-values-become-corrupted-in-qt-5)).

I am using the test example that is on the software page ([example](https://sourceforge.net/p/presage/presage/ci/master/tree/doc/getting_started.txt))

What I have tried to do:
My .pro file:

```
QT -= gui
CONFIG += c++11 console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

PRESAGE_ROOT = $$(PRESAGE_ROOT)
isEmpty(PRESAGE_ROOT) {         
    unix {
        PRESAGE_ROOT = /usr/local/
    }
}
! exists($${PRESAGE_ROOT}) {
        error(PRESAGE_ROOT does not exist.)
}

SOURCES += main.cpp
INCLUDEPATH   = $${PRESAGE_ROOT}/include
LIBS += -L$${PRESAGE_ROOT}/lib -lpresage
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <QCoreApplication> 
#include <QDebug>
#include <QVector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "presage.h"

class ExampleCallback : public PresageCallback
{
public:
    ExampleCallback(const std::string& _past_context) : past_context(_past_context) { }

    std::string get_past_stream() const { return past_context; }
    std::string get_future_stream() const { return empty; }

private:
    const std::string& past_context;
    const std::string empty;

};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    std::string context;
    ExampleCallback callback(context);
    Presage presage(&callback);

    std::string buffer;
    std::vector< std::string > predictions;

    for (;;) {
        std::cout << "> ";
        getline(std::cin, buffer);
        context += buffer;

        qInfo() << "context: " << QString::fromUtf8(presage.context().c_str());

        try {
           predictions = presage.predict();
        } catch(...) {
           std::exception_ptr p = std::current_exception();
           std::clog <<(p ? p.__cxa_exception_type()->name() : "null") << std::endl;
        }

        //QVector<std::string> vector = QVector<std::string>::fromStdVector(presage.predict());

        qInfo() << predictions.size(); //return 0


    }

    return a.exec();
}
```

When I check the context variable(presage->context()), it's ok because the context has the letters that I'm typing.

Compiling with g++ the example([example](https://sourceforge.net/p/presage/presage/ci/master/tree/doc/getting_started.txt)) works fine.

the platform on which I currently work:

```
   - g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) 5.4.0 20160609
   - Qt5.9.2
```

Thank you.